# Tengo una div que sera una galeria ,que se llena con imágenes que se cargan a un directorio , como puedo ocultarlo si el directorio esta vacio?

Tags: php, html, css

Tengo el siguiente div, abajo de un formulario , en el formulario puedo cargar imagenes que van a un directorio , me las muestra bien , el problema es que cuando no tengo nada en el directorio me aparece la imagen del icono roto , como puedo puedo ocultar eso

```
<div style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">
        <img src="<?=$imagen;?>" style="width: 180px; height: 180px;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con el siguiente comando podes obtener el total de archivos que hay en una carpeta
Luego podes hacer un if que si $total_imagenes es igual a 0 no muestre el div

imghh seria la carpeta que arme para el ejemplo ahi va el nombre de la carpeta donde vos tenes las imagenes:

```
<?php

$total_imagenes = count(glob('imghh/{*.jpg,*.gif,*.png}',GLOB_BRACE));

if ($total_imagenes > 0) {
    echo $total_imagenes;
}
else{
    echo "No hay imagenes en la carpeta";
}
```

Carpeta sin imagenes

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Carpeta con imagenes

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: muchas gracias me sirvio mucho esto

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo que haría sería directamente no pintar el `div` en caso de no tener ninguna imagen que mostrar. Por lo que he entendido de tu explicación algo así te podría valer:

**PHP**

```
if ($imagen != '') {
    echo '<div style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">';
    echo '<img src="' . $imagen . '" style="width: 180px; height: 180px;">';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu código debería arrojarte una notificación (si todos los avisos de error están activos), a no ser que guardes un string vacío en la variable `$imagen`, de ser así, con el siguiente código evitas que se muestre el elemento *img*, si no tienes una imagen:

```
<div style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">
<?php
    if (isset($imagen) && $imagen) {
?>
        <img src="<?=$imagen;?>" style="width: 180px; height: 180px;">
<?php
    }
?>
</div>
```

y que salte la notificación, por tratar de usar la variable sino está definida o vale null.

Para que no se muestre directamente el *div* vacío, cosa que no se si rompe tu diseño, pon todo el contenido del *div* dentro del condicional.

> Actualización:

Con **respecto a las validaciones**, el siguiente código:

```
<?php
if ($imagen) {
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'error';
}
```

genera un mensaje de error cómo: `Notice: Undefined variable: imagen in ...`

Para prevenir esto, podemos usar [isset()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php) o bien inicializar la variable antes de usarla, en cuyo caso el código:

```
<?php
$imagen = '';
if ($imagen) {
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'error';
}
```

imprime: `error`, pero PHP no lanza ningún error.